# Execute 64bit app from 32bit PHP instance on 64bit Windows?

Tags: php, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am wanting to know the trick to start WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) from my 32bit instance of PHP on Windows 10.

Currently, what is working on 64bit PHP is:

```
popen('start "My App" "wsl" "php" "thescriptorun.php"');
```

That line of code will open a new CMD window and run my PHP script file inside a WSL instance.  Pretty cool.

However, I have instances where I may have to support 32bit PHP, particularly during development as the IDE tool used will only automatically install 32bit PHP and, due to company policy BS, I am stuck using Visual Studio on Windows.

It seems that because PHP is 32bit when it executes 'start' it does so as a 32bit instance, so basically 64bit apps are invisible to it and I get a "Windows cannot find 'wsl'" message.

[image: WSL not found error]

Keep in mind it is the exact same line of code that works on 64bit PHP.

I'm currently throwing a very angry Exception on 32bit PHP saying the operation is not supported, but I'm wondering if anyone knows "the trick" to get the start program to execute in a 64bit instance.

Comment: Can you start "cmd /c wsl"?

Comment: No.  Try it.  From 32bit PHP you will get the above error.  In fact, to test this I did "start cmd" without WSL at all, then changed directory to \Windows\System32 which is where the wsl.exe file lives, and you can't see it.  Do the same thing in 64bit PHP and it's there.

Comment: Try this environment variable `"%windir%\Sysnative\wsl.exe"`.